# Host to add /usr/bin/host to scratch Dockerfile consisting of Go binary?

Tags: docker, go, dockerfile

I would like for this very simple Go package to run in a Docker container using Scratch (or minimal) image.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "os/exec"
)

func main() {
    cmd := "host"
    args := []string{"-t", "ns", "google.com"}
    output, err := exec.Command(cmd, args...).Output()
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }
    fmt.Println(string(output))
}
```

My original Dockerfile is as follows:

```
FROM scratch
ADD gohost /
CMD ["/gohost"]
```

This results in `exit code 0: exec: "host": executable file not found in $PATH`

I figure this means I need to `ADD` the /usr/bin/host and set `ENV` on the added host.. but all the random combinations I've tried of this failed..

I've also tried to simply change `cmd := "host"` to point to the host binary I added (`cmd := "/host"`), but seems that isn't a possibility either.

Also, I'm not sure if it's relevant, but it's important the Go binary is built with `env GOOS=linux GOARCH=arm64 go build`.

Comment: move `host` executable into docker's path namespace.

Comment: @nilsocket could you clarify? I've tried `ADD /usr/bin/host /bin` and `/usr/bin` but that didn't work, and when I changed the Go code to point to the binary, e.g. `cmd := "/host"` then I made sure that the binary was located in that path, e.g. `ADD /usr/bin/host /`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're depending on calling external binaries, either you also need to make sure they're statically-compiled and included in your Dockerfile, or you can't use a `FROM scratch` image.  A merely very small base image might work better.

In many cases there is a Go-native library to do what you need, and you might see if you can change your code to not need an external process.  For instance, instead of calling `host` as an external process, you might call [`net.LookupHost`](https://godoc.org/net#LookupHost) instead.

Some common tools are available in [busybox](https://busybox.net) ([image](https://hub.docker.com/_/busybox/)), including an `nslookup` but not a `host` or a `dig`, but usually these are the sorts of things where an in-process library call will do better.  Otherwise you need a lightweight base Linux distribution like [alpine](https://hub.docker.com/_/alpine/) where you can [add software](https://pkgs.alpinelinux.org/contents?file=host&path=&name=&branch=edge&repo=main&arch=x86_64); your Dockerfile would be

```
FROM alpine
RUN apk add bind-tools
COPY gohost /bin
CMD ["gohost"]
```

The Alpine base image advertises itself as being only 5 MB, so your image will be bigger than a `FROM scratch` image but still not huge.

Comment: This worked, thanks a lot! The reason I wanted to use `host` is because I believed it would be much more performant, but I had been testing up against a Go package (github.com/miekg/dns) and not net.LookupHost.. the dns package felt a bit slow, but net.LookupHost seems just as fast as /usr/bin/host (https://play.golang.org/p/J2_TWGMCfog)